Fitting data to a Log-normal distribution (2)
I used the stack exchange code to fit a Gaussian Model to
sizeDist = {0.04, 0.07, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3., 4., 5., 6., 6.5, 7., 7.5, 8., 8.5, 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 22., 25., 28., 32., 36., 38., 40., 45., 50., 53., 56., 63., 71., 75., 80., 85., 90., 95., 100., 106., 112., 125., 130., 140., 145., 150., 160., 170., 180., 190., 200., 212., 242., 250., 300., 400., 500., 600., 700., 800., 900., 1000., 1100., 1200., 1300., 1400., 1500., 1600., 1700., 1800., 1900., 2000., 2100., 2200., 2300., 2400., 2500.}

pdfValues = 
{0., 0., 0., 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0009,0.0011, 0.0011, 0.0013, 0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0018, 0.0021, 0.0026, 0.0031, 0.0035, 0.0041, 0.0047, 0.0055, 0.0058, 0.0067, 0.0078, 0.0091, 0.011, 0.0131, 0.0162, 0.0186, 0.0221, 0.0263, 
0.0299, 0.0325, 0.0344, 0.0357, 0.0364, 0.0369, 0.0373, 0.0375, 0.0377, 0.0382, 0.0389, 0.0395, 0.0394, 0.039, 0.0386, 0.0382, 0.0369, 0.0343, 0.0319, 0.0297, 0.0265, 0.0206, 0.0158, 0.0127, 0.0097, 0.007, 0.0046, 0.003, 0.0018, 0.0008, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

using
ClearAll[guassianFit];
Options[guassianFit] = {"Opt" -> "Parameters", "Opt" -> "Plot"};

guassianFit[pdfValues_, sizeDistribution_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{data, a, b, \[Mu], \[Sigma], z, nlm, params},
  \[Sigma] =.;
  data = Transpose[{Log10@sizeDistribution, pdfValues}];
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,
    {a + b Exp[-((\[Mu] - z)^2/(2. \[Sigma]^2))], \[Sigma] > 0.},
    {a, b, \[Mu], \[Sigma]}, z,
    Method -> "NMinimize"
    ];
  params = nlm["BestFitParameters"];(*Print[params];*)
  
  Switch[OptionValue["Opt"],
   "Parameters", params,
   "Plot",
   Show[
    ListPlot[data,
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[81, 1], PlotLegends -> {"Data"}],
    
    Plot[
     Normal@nlm, {z, Min@Log10@sizeDistribution, 
      Max@Log10@sizeDistribution},
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[81, 3], PlotLegends -> {"Log-Normal"},
     FrameLabel -> {"log10 of Particle Size (\[Mu]m)", 
       "PDF by Volume"}],
    PlotLabel -> params[[3 ;;]], PlotRange -> All]
   ]]


My understanding is that I can use the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ derived from the guassian Fit directly in LogNormalDistribution[$\mu$, $\sigma$] but the $\sigma$ = - 0.3 <0.
How can I fix this issue? or How can I fit a LogNormalDistribution to the data?

Would you describe how you obtained "pdf" values from a distribution?  It appears (just as in the link you provided) that a regression is to be performed using a curve  that is a multiple of a log normal distribution rather than estimating the parameters of a log normal distribution from a random sample.

I get a positive [Sigma] -> 0.484448 from your code.

@JimB. I used the code from that link, not the data. Data comes from analyzing sediment samples taken in a river.

@Daniel. Technically Sigma can be Abs[Sigma] as it's squared ... But it's interesting! Can you share what is your Mu and Sigma?
In general I believe, the Mu and Siga from this code cannot be plugged in LogNormalDistribution[Mu,Sigma] directly.

Here is the output from your code. I have MMA Version 14.1: {a -> 0.0156779,
b -> -0.021301, [Mu] -> 2.80193, [Sigma] -> 0.484448}

I should have been more explicit.  What are the pdfValues ?  My guess is that they are the relative frequencies:  counts of observations in each "bin" divided by total number of  observations (as they add up to almost exactly 1).  The total number of observations is need to estimate precision of the estimates.  And I assume that sizeDist is the mid-point of each bin?

A regression approach is rarely appropriate for fitting a probability distribution.  (Maybe in some cases to get starting values for the parameters but, again, that's rare.)  However, that inappropriate approach pops up in this forum relatively frequently.
I'm going to assume that what you have is a random sample of sediment values and you've binned those values and that pdfValues represents the bin counts divided by the total number of observations.  Further, I'm going to assume that the total sample size is 1,000.
So to get the counts and the borders for the bins I use the following:
n = 1000;
counts = Floor[n * pdfValues + 0.5]
(* {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 15, 18, 21, 26, 31, 35, 41, 47, 55,
   58, 67, 78, 91, 110, 131, 162, 186, 221, 263, 299, 325, 344, 357, 364, 369, 373, 375,
   377, 382, 389, 395, 394, 390, 386, 382, 369, 343, 319, 297, 265, 206, 158, 127, 97, 70,
   46, 30, 18, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)

bins = Join[{0}, Table[(sizeDist[[i]] + sizeDist[[i - 1]])/2, {i, 2, Length[sizeDist]}], {\[Infinity]}]
(* {0, 0.055, 0.085, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.05, 1.15, 1.25,
    1.35, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.25, 6.75, 7.25, 7.75, 8.25,
    8.75, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 21., 23.5, 26.5,
    30., 34., 37., 39., 42.5, 47.5, 51.5, 54.5, 59.5, 67., 73., 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 92.5,
    97.5, 103., 109., 118.5, 127.5, 135., 142.5, 147.5, 155., 165., 175., 185., 195., 206., 
    227., 246., 275., 350., 450., 550., 650., 750., 850., 950., 1050., 1150., 1250., 1350.,
    1450., 1550., 1650., 1750., 1850., 1950., 2050., 2150., 2250., 2350., 2450., \[Infinity]} *)

Now construct the log of the likelihood and find the values of the parameters that maximize the likelihood.
logL = Sum[If[counts[[i]] == 0, 0,
  counts[[i]] Log[CDF[LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], bins[[i]]] - 
    CDF[LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], bins[[i - 1]]]]],
  {i, 2, Length[counts]}] // Quiet;
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, \[Sigma] > 0}, {{\[Mu], 1}, {\[Sigma], 1}}]
(* {-37474.7, {\[Mu] -> 3.01287, \[Sigma] -> 0.835711}} *)

To plot your data (i.e., the "histogram" that you presented) against the pdf of a normal distribution, we need to get the area under the curve of the connected data points to sum to 1 to have the proper scaling.
areaUnderCurve = Sum[If[pdfValues[[i]] == 0, 0, 
  (Log[bins[[i + 1]]] - Log[bins[[i]]]) pdfValues[[i]]],
  {i, 1, Length[pdfValues] - 1}];
Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{Log[sizeDist], pdfValues/areaUnderCurve}]], 
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]] /. mle[[2]], z], {z, 
   Log[Min[sizeDist]], Log[Max[sizeDist]]}]]


This doesn't look like a great fit to a normal distribution (which also means not a good fit to a lognormal distribution).  An additional observation is that the plot of the "histogram" looks much too smooth for the data to be a random sample from any distribution unless the sample size is maybe in the millions or if some smoothing was performed.
If the fit didn't look so bad, I would recommend estimating estimates of precision for the parameter estimates.  That can be done using the log of the likelihood but I'll wait to see if I've guessed correctly about your data before adding that.

@ JimB, The data is coming from analyzing particles in 1 quart of water and it's done by a machine. No smoothing was done.
We have tens of these samples that look more or less alike.

Good.  So does the "raw" data consist of counts in each of the bins?  And are the 'pdfValues` counts divided by some factor?  The distribution certainly has a shape similar to a normal but there are definite deviations from a normal so that one shouldn't consider the data from a normal distribution.

ClearAll[logNormalFit];
Options[logNormalFit] = {"Opt" -> "Parameters", "Opt" -> "Plot"};

logNormalFit[pdfValues_, sizeDistribution_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{integral, scaledpdf, data, \[Mu], \[Sigma], x, nlm, params},
  
  integral = 
   Total[Differences@Prepend[sizeDistribution, 0.] pdfValues];
  scaledpdf = pdfValues/integral;
  
  data = Transpose[{sizeDistribution, scaledpdf}];
  
  Clear[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
  logNormalModel[x_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_] := 
   PDF[LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x];
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
    logNormalModel[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma]], {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, x, 
    Weights -> scaledpdf];
  params = nlm["BestFitParameters"];
  
  Switch[OptionValue["Opt"],
   "Parameters", params,
   "Plot",
   Show[
    ListLogLinearPlot[data,
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[81, 1], PlotLegends -> {"Data"}],
    
    LogLinearPlot[
     logNormalModel[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma]] /. params, {x, 
      Min[sizeDistribution], Max[sizeDistribution]},
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[81, 3], PlotLegends -> {"Log-Normal"}, 
     PlotRange -> All],
    PlotLabel -> params, PlotRange -> All,
    FrameLabel -> {"Particle Size (\[Mu]m)", "PDF by Volume"}]
   ]
  ]


